# Does Wordpress load-cache functions such as wp_get_nav_menu_object?

Tags: caching, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been asking myself this question for quite a while. Maybe someone has already done some digging (or is involved in WP) to know the answer.

I'm talking about storing objects from WP-functions in PHP variables, for the duration of a page load, e.g. to avoid having to query the database twice for the same result set.

I **don't** mean caching in the sense of pre-rendering dynamic pages and saving them in HTML format for faster retrieval.

Quite a few "template tags" (Wordpress functions) may be used multiple times in a theme during one page load. When a theme or plugin calls such a function, does WP run a database query every time to retrieve the necessary data, and does it parse this data every time to return the desired object?

Or, does the function store the its result in a PHP variable the first time it runs, and checks if it already exists before it queries the database or parses?

Examples include:

`wp_get_nav_menu_object()`

`wp_get_nav_menu_items()`

`wp_list_categories()`

`wp_tag_cloud()`

`wp_list_authors()`

...but also such important functions as `bloginfo()` or `wp_nav_menu()`.

Of course, it wouldn't make much sense to cache any and all queries like post-related ones. But for the above examples (there are more), I believe it would.

So far, I've been caching these generic functions myself when a theme required the same function to be called more than once on a page, by writing my own functions or classes and caching in global or static variables. I don't see why I should add to the server load by running the exact same generic query more than a single time.

Does this sort of caching already exist in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for some queries and functions. See [WP Object Cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache). The relevant functions are `wp_cache_get`, `wp_cache_set`, `wp_cache_add`, and `wp_cache_delete`. You can find these functions being used in many places through the WordPress code to do exactly what you are describing.